# How to center a timeline with blocks in the middle?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I managed to make a mockup of a timeline with blocks. It has a look that is ok. You can run the snippet to take a look or see this image:

[image]

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.border {
  width: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 2px auto;
}

.bubble,
.big-bubble {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.big-bubble {
  padding: 30px 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="border"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="big-bubble"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="border"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="big-bubble"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="border"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="big-bubble"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I'm not satisfied with the result. I would like to align my timeline like this. The idea would be that the info bubble on the right starts in the vertical middle of the bubble on the left.

[image]

I don't see how to do it with flex.

Comment: maybe add a `div` before `div class="big-bubble`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just give `.right` a `margin-top` that is equal to half the height of `.left` (`11px`)?

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 11px;
}

.border {
  width: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 2px auto;
}

.bubble,
.big-bubble {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.big-bubble {
  padding: 30px 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="border"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="big-bubble"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="border"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="big-bubble"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="border"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="big-bubble"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alteratively, if you don't want the increased gap, you can just give `.left` a `margin-top` of `-11px`:

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: -11px;
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.border {
  width: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 2px auto;
}

.bubble,
.big-bubble {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.big-bubble {
  padding: 30px 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="border"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="big-bubble"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="border"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="big-bubble"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="border"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="big-bubble"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yep, margin-top: -11px is working thank you! it's that simple:)

Answer (score 0):

By adding a `margin-top` on the `.right` class you would have the below result:

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 10px;
  /* line I adde */
  margin-top:0.7rem;
}

.border {
  width: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 2px auto;
}

.bubble,
.big-bubble {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.big-bubble {
  padding: 30px 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="border"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="big-bubble"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="border"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="big-bubble"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="bubble"></div>
      <div class="border"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="big-bubble"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not bad but the right bubble does not reach the next "middle" of the left bubble